# can we use html button onclick event inside php?

Tags: php, html

I am using an onclick event of a input button whose code is written inside php.. code is written below
this select() function isn't calling when i'm clicking the button. even i tried to show alert message on button click .. it also not working. kindly help ...

```html
<?php
echo"<td width=14% align=center><input type=button value=Export onclick=select() /></td>";

?>
```

Comment: You should use ajax for that. You cannot call a php function from javascript directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the name `select` to someother name like `myselect` and it should work.

> You should not have the function name as `select`

**This should work for you**

```
<?php
echo"<td width=14% align=center><input type=button value=Export onclick=myselect() /></td>";
?>
<script>
    function myselect()
    {
        console.log('Clicked');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming select() is a PHP function, no. PHP is executed on the server side, whereas the HTML onclick event is interpreted by your browser, so one cannot access the other. Have the button link to a new PHP script instead. The new script can then call the select() function.